# Run Duration in SAS enterprise miner

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

I have the following problem. We have several streams in Enterprise Miner and we would like to be able to tell how long was each run. I have tried to create a macro that would save the start and end time/date but the problem is that global variables defined in a node, are not seen anymore in a subsequent node (so are global only inside a node, but not between nodes). How people usually solve the problem? Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks, Umberto

Comment: Can't you just print timestamps to the log at key stages (beginning, middle,end?) and then retrieve them from log? regex will help.

Comment: Theoretically yes. The problem is that the developer is not used to write sas code and is using only the nodes without code. So I was wondering if there is a way of putting a code node at the beginning and one at the end to get automatically the duration (the difference of start and end).

Comment: ok - give me 5 min there may be a work around

Comment: Have a look at my 2nd solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out timestamps to log (EM should produce a global log in the same fashion that EG and DI do)

Either use:

```
data _null_;  
 datetime = datetime();
 put datetime= datetime20.;
 run;
```

or macro language:

```
%put EM node started at at %sysfunc(time(),timeampm.) on %sysfunc(date(),worddate.).;
```

with a higly customised message you have read the log in SAS looking for those strings using regex.

**Solution 2:**

Other option is to created a table in a library that is visible from EM and EG for example and have sql inserts at the beginning/end of your process.

```
proc sql;
create table EM_logger 
    (jobcode char(100),
     timestamp num informat=datetime20. format=datetime20.);
quit;
proc sql;
insert into EM_logger values('Begining Linear Reg',%sysfunc(datetime()));
quit;

data w;
do i=1 to 10000000;
output;
end;
run;

proc sql;
insert into EM_logger values('End Linear Reg',%sysfunc(datetime()));
quit;
```

Table layout can be as complex as you want and as long as you can access it you can get your statistics.

Hope it helps

Comment: you can do the `inserts` with data steps - that's another option

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will mark it as the answer. I think is flexible enough. Need to talk to the developers to know what they really need...